# Background image over entire <main> element

Tags: javascript, css, html

My goal is to have a background image over the entire `<main>` element but the `<main>` element does not expand to the bottom of the page (or in my case to the footer) what can I do because the `<main>` just ends in the middle of the page?

```css
html {
   height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

 /* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
#fullmain {
 padding-top: 109px;
   padding-bottom: 86px;
   text-align: center;
    
    background: #f5f5f5 url(" http://pre06.deviantart.net/2bf3/th/pre/i/2010/284/b/d/autumn_fortest_ii_by_lotusonlinede-d30jn9b.jpg") no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;
   min-height: 100%;
    

}


#header {
 background-color: #25211e;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #1d1a18;
 text-align: center;
 position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 103px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    z-index: 99;

}

#heading {
    font-family: "titlefont";
 color: #c1b497;
 font-size: 45px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

 /* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */


#footer {
    background-color: #25211e;
 border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
   right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 80px;
   z-index: 98;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

#credit {
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 14px;
 color: #c1b497;
 font-weight: 600;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="all">
   <header id="header">
               <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
            </header>
   <main id="fullmain">
   </main>
   <footer id="footer">
    <p id="credit">Footer</p>
   </footer>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you have to share the effort you have done which is source code.

Comment: put it on the body element. body {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set your #all tag to height 100% also

```
#all {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Enjoy =]

Comment: Ive been victim of that a few times amigo =]

Answer (score 0):

The image is in the entire Background, I just add the position and width to #fullmain id.

```css
html {
   height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

 /* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
#fullmain {
 
text-align: center;
background: #ec2222 url(http://pre06.deviantart.net/2bf3/th/pre/i/2010/284/b/d/autumn_fortest_ii_by_lotusonlinede-d30jn9b.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
    

}


#header {
 background-color: #25211e;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #1d1a18;
 text-align: center;
 position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 103px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    z-index: 99;

}

#heading {
    font-family: "titlefont";
 color: #c1b497;
 font-size: 45px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

 /* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */


#footer {
    background-color: #25211e;
 border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
   right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 80px;
   z-index: 98;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

#credit {
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 14px;
 color: #c1b497;
 font-weight: 600;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="all">
   <header id="header">
               <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
            </header>
   <main id="fullmain">
   </main>
   <footer id="footer">
    <p id="credit">Footer</p>
   </footer>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```